# Thousand separator in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

I am working on an R shiny application, I have an interactive chart in ggplotly. I would like space as a thousand separators, I have a code that is not really working.

Here's my code:

```
mrg <- list(l=10, r=10, b=10, t=100, pad=1)
      
        output$sortie3_evo <- renderPlotly({
          g <- ggplot(filtered_data_evo(), aes(x=Année.Scolaire, y= Nombre.élèves, fill=Secteur,label = format(as.numeric(..y..), nsmall=0, big.mark=" ")))+
          stat_summary(fun = sum, geom = "bar", position = position_dodge(0.9))+
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=25, hjust=1))+
            facet_wrap(~ NiveauLV, ncol = 2) +
            xlab("")

            
g <- ggplotly(g) %>%
              layout(margin = mrg)

          })
```

It gives me the following result:

[image]

The last line of the hover shows the correct thing, but I don't understand why it also shows the code. If anyone has a solution?

Here's a part of my data using `dput()`:

```
structure(list(Année.Scolaire = c("2018-2019", "2018-2019", "2018-2019", 
"2018-2019", "2018-2019", "2018-2019", "2018-2019", "2018-2019", 
"2018-2019", "2018-2019"), Secteur = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("PUBLIC", "PRIVE SOUS CONTRAT"
), class = "factor"), Département = c("ARDECHE", "ARDECHE", "HAUTE SAVOIE", 
"SAVOIE", "HAUTE SAVOIE", "HAUTE SAVOIE", "ISERE", "ISERE", "ISERE", 
"SAVOIE"), Cycle = c("Cycle 2", "Cycle 3", "Cycle 2", "Cycle 3", 
"Cycle 1", "Cycle 3", "Cycle 1", "Cycle 2", "Cycle 3", "Cycle 1"
), LV = c("Allemand LV1", "Allemand LV1", "Allemand LV1", "Allemand LV1", 
"Allemand LV1", "Allemand LV1", "Allemand LV1", "Allemand LV1", 
"Allemand LV1", "Allemand LV1"), Nombre.élèves = c(6, 6, 6, 324, 
66, 3, 21, 258, 18, 204), NiveauLV = c("LV1", "LV1", "LV1", "LV1", 
"LV1", "LV1", "LV1", "LV1", "LV1", "LV1"), LV_recode = c("Allemand", 
"Allemand", "Allemand", "Allemand", "Allemand", "Allemand", "Allemand", 
"Allemand", "Allemand", "Allemand")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: I just did it, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `text` aesthetic and you could create a label hover text using `paste` like this:

```r
mrg <- list(l=10, r=10, b=10, t=100, pad=1)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
g <- ggplot(filtered_data_evo, aes(x=Année.Scolaire, y= Nombre.élèves, fill=Secteur,text = paste("label:", format(after_stat(y), big.mark=" "))))+
    stat_summary(fun = sum, geom = "bar", position = position_dodge(0.9))+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=25, hjust=1))+
    facet_wrap(~ NiveauLV, ncol = 2) +
    xlab("")

g <- ggplotly(g) %>%
    layout(margin = mrg)
g
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Edit**

To select certain `aes` in your hover text, you could use `tooltip` with the right aesthetics like this:

```
g <- ggplotly(g, tooltip = c("x", "fill", "text")) %>%
    layout(margin = mrg) 
g
```

Comment: It's working, however, now it displays the y value two times in the hover.

Comment: Hi @Chloé, you should add `tooltip = c("x", "fill", "text")` to your `ggplotly` so you will have only one y value.

Comment: @Chloé, I added some explanation and code above.